# Watch The Flash Season 6 Episode 9 via Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, spam

I ended up searching for *stack overflow* instead of browsing to the site which gave me search results which had some unexpected content:

[image: Things that link to Stack Overflow CVs that shouldn't]

These images go through to the following addresses:

- https://stackoverflow.com/story/joker-2019-full-movie-online
- https://stackoverflow.com/cv/watch-frozen-2-2019-queen-elsa-full-movie-free-online
- https://stackoverflow.com/cv/full-watch-the-flash-season-6-episode-9-the-cw-online-free

It would appear that someone has found an, erm, interesting way to share links to content by leveraging Stack Overflow!

*[I've tagged this as a bug, rather than support or discussion as it felt like the best fit]*

Comment: Joy.  Spammers have found developer stories and resumes.  These generally stick around because there's no oversight on them, so they fly under the radar.

Comment: I don't want to live on this planet anymore.

Comment: Unrelated: "Rob is a new contributor. Be nice..." <looks at Rob, he has 41k rep>

Comment: @fbueckert, yeah, 10 points for deviousness at least!

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate 50% down to all my activity here having ended up being migrated to meta.se when it was created and 50% proof that not all "highly active SO users" (for a given definition) are actually active in any way/shape/form on meta =)

Comment: Are we going to end up with a review queue for CVs?

Comment: … I can imagine the buttons: "Looks OK," "Spam," "Needs to go back to school."

Comment: @Rob It's actually a fairly common process for them; I've run into these things on other sites.  They seem to use any personal type area to create these filled with as many tags for SEO as they can.  Google got rid of spam sites to generate SEO, so now user pages are a target.

Comment: I've destroyed these filthy spammers.

Comment: @codyGray I can still see this first "story" ? Is that just because of the direct link, or ... ?

Comment: Dunno, @JonasWilms. It was definitely gone when I checked  earlier. I got a 404 when I tried to view the page. When I tried just now, after reading your comment, it worked. So, the spammer must have recreated their Careers profile. I have destroyed the whole account now, so it should be gone. Again.

Comment: @codyGray same for the second link ... I guess it's time for some more drastic methods (IP ban?)

Comment: @CodyGray Links 1 and 2 still lead to spam.

Comment: @James, I raised a flag (as suggested in the dupe) earlier as that should hopefully get picked up quicker =)

Comment: Sounds like someone's managed to exploit a submission loophole to ensure these things stick around.  They've probably dropped Flash because it's no longer relevant.

Comment: I've cleaned up the mess again, and put in a requisition for bigger guns. We'll see what happens...

Comment: @CodyGray, I'm sad to say that Frozen is back in full glory and Joker has appeared again but appears to be laying low with a somewhat empty profile; probably in preparation for a link filled update at a later date :-/